# laravel validations for a current database value

Tags: laravel, validation

This is a update function validation.So far I have done something like this,

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'vehicle_id'=>'required',
            'date_from'=>'required|date|before_or_equal:date_to|after_or_equal:today',
            'date_to'=>'required|date|after_or_equal:date_from|after_or_equal:today',
            'time_from'=>'required',
            'time_to'=>'required',
            'event_id'=>'required',

        ]);
```

now i want to add new validation called as **meter_reading** that should be greater than the current database meter_reading.How should I do that?

Comment: You'll need to write custom validation rule to achieve that.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#custom-validation-rules might help